# URI templating in Guzzle6?

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle6

I am not able to use URI templating in Guzzle 6.

My code(Updated):

`self::$client = new Client(["base_uri" => "http://example.com/api/", "cookies" => true]);
$result = self::$client->get(["project/{projectId}", ["projectId" => $projectId]]);`

I've checked [this](http://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/http-client/uri-templates.html) old documentation and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259628/uri-templates-in-guzzle-5) question but can't make it work.

Exception thrown is: URI must be a string or UriInterface.

I can't find any documentation related to this for Guzzle 6.

Comment: add the whole code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guzzle's `get` method definition is `get(string|UriInterface $uri, array $options = [])` and you are passing array as `$uri` which is not allowed here.
You have to build uri yourself, since guzzle does not do that for you.

Correct chunk of code should look like this (if `projectId` is an integer):

`$result = self::$client->get(sprintf('project/%d', $projectId));`